# Resizing JPEG images in Laravel using Imagick driver

Tags: php, laravel-5, imagick, intervention

I am resizing images in my laravel application and I'm using Intervention with imagick driver. I just want to ask why is it that even if the size of the image is 300x300px, its file size is 600kb. I would have thought that it should have been like 70-100kb.

What could be the reason behind this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example image?

Comment: Sorry sir I can't post images. If you could answer theoretically that would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Theoretically, something is fucky. 300 pixels wide * 300 pixels high * 4 bytes per pixel is 360kB of data. Even with no compression, the image size you say you have is almost twice as big as it should be. Either you are just looking at the wrong files, or something horrible has happened to the images. If you can't provide any example image, it's not possible for people to understand what the problem actually is.

Comment: Hi sir, i'm still stucked in this kind of problem, it seems I am the only experiencing this, i just wanted to ask what you meant by this statement: "something horrible has happened to the images"? 
Btw, I just edited the original image in Windows Paint then resize it there like I did in my project 300px by 300px, and it gives the same file size. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust a quality it's a very simple to do:

```
// save file as jpg with medium quality
$img->save('public/bar.jpg', 60);
```

or without a filename:

```
// save with medium quality
$img->save(null, 60);
```

Please take a look on `->save` method description: http://image.intervention.io/api/save:

> Define optionally the quality of the image. It is normalized for all
>   file types to a range from 0 (poor quality, small file) to 100 (best
>   quality, big file).

The last function used for this example (with `GD` as an image processing driver) is [imagejpeg](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Encoder.php#L15) which has a `quality` parameter. Or [setimagecompressionquality](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Imagick/Encoder.php#L26) (with `Imagick` as an image processing driver).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already know that. I actually even used a zero quality and it's very pixelated, but the point is my 100% quality image size is 600kb then when I compress it to zero quality it just becomes 588kb? I don't think the compression is really that much useful. Do you have recommendations sir?